# That occurs copy operation when casting pointer to reference?

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    operator T& (void)
    {
        return *this->ref; // this code occurs copy operation?
    }

public:
    T* ref;
}
```

In this situration, I want to know about that I have overhead for cast T* to T&. I think that code is have a overhead because '*this->ref' operation have copy or something for get reference of T.

Comment: There is no copy here. The reference being returned is bound to the object pointed to by `ref`.

Comment: @M.M So actually `*this->ref` return a reference for T? I didn't get it about your advice.. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No copy is made when a pointer is dereferenced. If the result of dereferencing a pointer---which is an lvalue---is used to *initialize* an object of the same type, then a copy occurs. In this code, no object is initialized---only a reference. When `T&` is initialized from an lvalue of type `T`, it binds directly, without creating any temporary object.

A copy would occur if the result of the conversion was used to initialize an object of type `T`.

```
Foo<T> f;
static_cast<T&>(f); // no copy
T x = f;            // copy
```

Comment: As far as I know `*this->ref` is returning a rvalue so that operation isn't have copy?

Comment: @TerNer Dereferencing a pointer yields an lvalue. No exceptions to this rule.

Comment: @TerNer the return type is `T&`, an lvalue reference,  this can only bind to lvalues